# Conditional variance of Y with Y-conditionally independent variables

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, variance, covariance

There is a random variable $Y$, and many signals about $Y$ denoted by $s_i \in \mathcal{S}$. This paper assumes that:

1. The signals are jointly Gaussian with $Y$;
2. $Y$ and all signals in $\mathcal{S}$ have zero mean and unit variance, i.e. $Y, s_i \sim N(0,1),\quad \forall i $;
3. Conditional on $Y$, the signals are pairwise independent, i.e. $s_i \bot  s_j\mid Y$ for $s_i, s_j \in \mathcal{S}$ and $i \not = j$.

According to the assuming above, the author calculated that the conditional variance of $Y$ given any $n$ signals is:

$$ v_n = Var(Y\mid s_1,...,s_n) = \frac{1-\rho^2}{1+\rho^2(n-1)}$$

and $\rho$ is the correlation coefficient between $Y$ and any signal $s_i, i = 1,...,n$.

**How to prove it?** Especially the denominator $1+\rho^2(n-1)$.

---

This question comes from paper below:

> Duffie, D., Malamud, S. and Manso, G. (2009), Information Percolation With Equilibrium Search Dynamics. Econometrica, 77: 1513-1574. https://doi.org/10.3982/ECTA8160

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the vector $(Y,s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ is jointly normal, the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $(s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ is univariate normal. Refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Conditional_distributions) section of the Wikipedia page for the conditional distributions their variances.

Let $\rho_{ij}$ be the correlation between $s_i$ and $s_j$ for $i\ne j$ and $\mathbf1_n$ be an $n\times 1$ vector of all-ones. The joint distribution of $(s_i,s_j,Y)$ is then multivariate normal with dispersion matrix

$$
\begin{bmatrix}1&\rho_{ij}&\rho\\ \rho_{ij}&1&\rho\\ \rho&\rho&1\end{bmatrix}=\left[\begin{array}{@{}c|c@{}}
  \begin{matrix}
  1 & \rho_{ij} \\
  \rho_{ij} & 1
  \end{matrix}
  & \rho\mathbf1_2 \\
\hline
  \rho\mathbf1_2^T &
 1
\end{array}\right]
$$

And $(s_i,s_j)$ given $Y$ is bivariate normal with dispersion matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&\rho_{ij}\\ \rho_{ij}&1\end{bmatrix}-(\rho \mathbf1_2)(\rho \mathbf1_2^T)=\begin{bmatrix}1&\rho_{ij}\\ \rho_{ij}&1\end{bmatrix}-\rho^2\mathbf1_2\mathbf1_2^T=\begin{bmatrix}1-\rho^2 &\rho_{ij}-\rho^2 \\ \rho_{ij}-\rho^2 & 1-\rho^2\end{bmatrix}$$

Since zero correlation is same as independence in multivariate normal distribution, for $(s_i,s_j)$ to be independent given $Y$, you must have

$$\operatorname{Cov}(s_i,s_j \mid Y)=0 \iff \rho_{ij}=\rho^2$$

Based on your description, the dispersion matrix of $(Y,s_1,\ldots,s_n)$ then takes the form

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&\rho&\rho&\cdots&\rho\\
\rho &1 &\rho^2 &\cdots &\rho^2\\
\rho &\rho^2 &1 &\cdots &\rho^2\\
\vdots &\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
\rho &\rho^2 & \rho^2 &\cdots &1
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & \rho \mathbf1_n^T \\
\rho\mathbf1_n &\Sigma_{22}
\end{bmatrix}\,,
$$

where

$$
\Sigma_{22}=\begin{bmatrix}
1 &\rho^2 &\cdots &\rho^2\\
\rho^2 &1 &\cdots &\rho^2\\
\vdots &\vdots &\ddots &\vdots\\
\rho^2 & \rho^2 &\cdots &1
\end{bmatrix}
=(1-\rho^2)I_n+\rho^2 \mathbf1_n\mathbf1_n^T
$$

Provided $\Sigma_{22}$ is invertible, the conditional variance is given by

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid s_1,\ldots,s_n)=1-(\rho\mathbf1_n^T) \Sigma_{22}^{-1}(\rho \mathbf1_n)$$

Using the [Sherman-Morrison formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherman%E2%80%93Morrison_formula), you have

$$\Sigma_{22}^{-1}=\frac1{1-\rho^2}I_n- \frac{\rho^2}{(1-\rho^2)(1+\rho^2(n-1))}\mathbf1_n\mathbf1_n^T$$

On simplification,

$$\operatorname{Var}(Y \mid s_1,\ldots,s_n)=1-\rho^2 \mathbf1_n^T \Sigma_{22}^{-1} \mathbf1_n=\frac{1-\rho^2}{1+\rho^2(n-1)}$$

Comment: Why $Cov (s_i, s_j \mid Y)$ in the disperation matrix is $(\rho_{ij} - \rho^2)$ ?

Comment: @StorageGuard.Osaka Check edit.

Comment: I got it. Knowing the covariance matrix of $(s_i, s_j, Y)$, we need to calculate the covariance of $(s_i, s_j)$ conditional on $Y$. Donating the block matrix as $\Sigma_{11}, \Sigma_{12}, \Sigma_{21}, \Sigma_{22}$,   the $Y$-conditional covariance of $(s_i, s_j)$ can be shown as $Cov(s_i, s_j \mid Y) = \Sigma_{11} - \Sigma_{12} \Sigma_{22}^{-1} \Sigma_{21}$, and then $(\rho_{ij} - \rho^2)$ is proved. That's right?

Comment: @StorageGuard.Osaka Pretty much, yes. In my notation, $Cov(s_i,s_j\mid Y)$ is the $(i,j)$th entry of the dispersion matrix of $(s_i,s_j)$ given $Y$.